# Unable to resolve the type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities:Activity'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I just checked out a version of MVC3 project and am getting this error when building it:

Unable to resolve the type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities:Activity' or one of its arguments. Ensure that the type name is correct or that the Assembly containing the type is loaded.

The files the compiler appears to be having a problem with is under 'BuildProcessTemplates' and are DefaultTemplate.xaml, LabDefaultTemplate.xaml and UpgradeTemplate.xaml.  I don't know what these files are but removing them gives me even more errors.

An error previous to this was 'Project file must include the .NET Framework assembly 'WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework' in the reference list' which, from googling, concerns xaml files' Build Action must be reset.

I don't know where to go from here.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4):

Adding reference to **System.Activities** will solve this issue,
 I would recommend to add reference to **System.Xaml** as well in case if you haven't added it,   this is also need for WF development